# How to get all sub fields from objects that contain in ArrayList?

Tags: java, android

this is the code

```
public class SomeObject
{
    private String _name;

    public String get_name() {
        return _name;
    }
}

public class SomeObjectContainer {
     private ArrayList<SomeObject>_objects;

    public ArrayList<SomeObject> get_objects() {
        return _objects;
    }
 }
```

My questions:

1. I want to implement some method in SomeObjectContainer that return a Array that will contain all the _objects._name. 
   Is there some easy way to do it without create new Array and scan all the _objects and pull out all the _name of every object in the _objects collection ?
2. If i already have this Array[String] - is there any way ( maybe syntax in java ) that make my work easier to find if some this Array contain some specific String ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to have an easier way you must use java 8 stream like below:

```
List<String> names= someObjects.stream().map(SomeObject::get_name).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and if you want to know if this list contains an specific String do as below :

```
if(names.contains("some string"))
{
    //do what you wanna do here
}
```